# Skype doesn't start from terminal (installation via snap)

Tags: ubuntu, skype, haskell-snap-framework

I have installed skype in my Ubuntu machine, using snap:

```
snap install skype --classic
```

Once installed, I added the folder `/snap/bin` to $PATH in order to call snap applications from any folder.

The problem that I have:

1-I cannot invoke skype from terminal, if I run `skype` from ubuntu terminal does nothing. How to invoke it from terminal?

2-My main objective is to control skype from terminal, any recommendations?

P.D: I can run skype clicking the icon in the desktop, and it works well.

Comment: Does nothing? No errors? Please post exact error messages.

Comment: Exactly, no errors, no messages... I just type 'skype', or '/snap/bin/skype' (in terminal) but prompt returns, thats all.

Comment: I hope you have reloaded your bash after updating the PATH, so it `sources` the new changes in PATH. after you run `skype` and you get nothing, can you right after that execute `echo $?` to see the exit code from the previous command?

Comment: Thanks Ron. I restarted ubuntu, and $PATH includes the "/snap/bin/" patch. After execute "skype", if I execute "echo $?", prompt returns 0

Comment: can you check the permissions 
and also as i checked in my local computer `/snap/bin/` files are actually a link to `/usr/bin/`  so can you check inside the dir and see that

Comment: also can you mention your Ubuntu's version

Comment: The Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS and it seems that permissions are correct inside /snap/bin : "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 abr 26 22:50 skype -> /usr/bin/snap"

Comment: and I'm logged in the terminal as root